# GRUB / Boot Manager, Boot 2 Wubi

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, wubi

I am in the process of setting up a WUBI Installation that I will store on my computers I use.

But instead of booting to the WUBI installation via the windows boot manager I want to be able to use a USB key to store a bootloader that then allows me to boot to the Wubi stored on C: (/dev/sda1)

Would I just install grub onto my memory stick and then add an entry to that to the WUBI disk or some kind of windows boot manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want wubi. It is now being discontinued. Also any abnormal shutdown may totally erase wubi as it is just a large file inside a NTFS formatted partition. Ok for testing but any long term use may lead to issues. 
Why not use USB flash drive as a persistent install or if larger a full install?

wubi direct boot where hd0 is boot drive, yours should be different, and it is in partition 2 which may als be different. So both hd0,2 and sda2 must change. May be sdb1 and hd1,1 if you only have one other drive. Boot drive is always hd0, but other drives usually are in BIOS order.

Not sure if this works when inside Windows or not. More to boot wubi when in its own partition.

```
menuentry "Wubi" {
insmod ntfs
set root=(hd0,2)
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2 loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ro       quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
}
```

Really old info on caveats:
Posts by meierfra. to use grub2 to directly boot wubi

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=8903013

Comment: Thanks I'l test it, I just saw WUBI as being the easiest way at trying to store ubuntu in a file on a Windows computer. I can't partition the computers I wish to put ubuntu on to. Nor edit the boot menu.